# Search a char element in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I want to search a char *key in my linked list.

This is my search function:

```
Bool search (linked_list_t *head, char *key) {
    // Base case
    if (head == NULL)
        return false;
    // If key is present in current node 
    if (my_strcmp(head->key, key) == 0){
        printf("la clé existe");
        return true;
    }      
    // Recur for remaining list
    return search(head->next, key);
}
```

This my main function :

```
int main(void){
    List *my_list = initialisation();
    insert_command(my_list, "34", 23);
    linked_list_t *element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
    char *line = NULL;
    char *key = NULL;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        line = my_readline();
        char arr[10][20];
        
        my_strtowordarray(line, arr);
        key = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < list_length(my_list); i++)
        {
            if (search(element, key)){
                printf("la clé existe");
                return (element->value);
            } else {
                return (-1);
            }
        }
    }
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my problem:
I execute my program and it returns me a "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Your code have many undefined things. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You allocated some buffer and assigned that to `element` but didn't initialize the allocated buffer. Therefore `head->key` have an indeterminate value and using that invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, here is what you are basically doing for your list:

```
linked_list_t *element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
...
        if (search(element, key)){
```

That's it. You dynamically allocate memory for `element`, but you never actually initialize it.

As a result, when you try to do:

```
Bool search (linked_list_t *head, char *key) {
    ...
    if (my_strcmp(head->key, key) == 0){
```

and particularly `head->key`, you are requesting for a field named `key` from the `head`, which is actually `element` from your main method, which is uninitialized.

That means that code invokes *Undefined Behavior*, since `head->key` has a garbage value.

You should initialize `head`.

PS: You could revisit the concept of the Single Linked List in C.  When I was a student, I found the code I have in [listmanagement.c](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-c/) extremely helpful.

Comment: Thank you @gsamaras end @MikeCAT for enlightened me on my error, in main function I initialize a list : ```List *my_list = initialisation();``` . In the initialisation() function I already initialize element-> key : ``` List *initialisation()
{
    List *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    linked_list_t *element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
    
    if (!is_empty_list(list)) {
        element->key = "0";
        element->value = 0;
        element->next = NULL;
        list->head = element;
    }
    return (list);
} ```

Comment: @Keys_fh you are right, I am wrong. You do initialize the list, but `element`, which in search method is going to be the head of the list is `uninitialized`. If `my_list` is already ready, why don't you pass that to the search method (well its head), instead of `element`? Why do you need `element`?